# responsive design watching with dev tool

Tags: javascript, css

i try to make my archive in html responsive but i don't see (when i use the dev tools ,the part of toggle device)the difference  between what i code for desk and what i code for a mobile screen.
i code `<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">` in html and this in the css file

```
@media  (max-width: 600px) {
    .Spotify {height: 500px;
    }
    .html{
      background-color: indianred;
    }
    .compra{
      width: 150px;
    }
  }
```

i don't know that i'm doing wrong

Comment: How are you trying to see this responsive code?  Can you include the html?  With the data given, it seems like this should work, but maybe you could add a little more context about exactly what you expect to see and how you're testing this code.

Answer (score 0):

For responsive design, you have to switch from browser to developer mode.
If you click the right mouse button on the browser, you can see "Inspect". 
( Chrome: "Inspect" , Firefox: "Inspect Element" )
Personally, I like chrome. :) 
This is a developer mode. 
And please see this  [Toggle device Toolbar (screenshot)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/I7Y8s.png) .

You can test your mobile style on multiple devices ( iPad Pro, iPad, iPhone ... ) 
If you want to test your style, you can choose "[Responsive (screenshot)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6pyqD.png) ".